# how to add this format 2019-2020 in mysql using spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have an error with this format 2019-2020. how to add this kind of format in mysql using spring boot?

```
package com.sansuriya.cms.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="session")

public class Session {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer sid;

@Column(name="session")
private String session;

@Column(name="status")
private String status;

public Integer getSid() {
    return sid;
}
public void setSid(Integer sid) {
    this.sid = sid;
}
public String getSession() {
    return session;
}
public void setSession(String session) {
    this.session = session;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}
```

addsession.html

[image]

Here, I mentioned Session field for String type. in that session column I need to add this 2019-2020.
while adding this value into mysql table it shows error.
This is my Error page

[image]

Here is my mysql table structure.

[image]

Comment: @Akina ya I have used VARCHAR data type

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors, code etc. Just copy the actual text into your question. That helps other people with the same issues because you can't search text from inside pictures.

Comment: i need solution

Comment: That's what all the questions here are about. There's few things that might get you there faster: A good & clear title & question, a short reproducible example and explanation of what you've done to try to solve your issue. Sorry to say but commenting that you need a solution isn't probably going to make any difference.

Comment: @jamesz problem solved